# Nodejs retrieving a Int32 from a uInt8Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, dataview

I receive a uInt8Array from a websocket, and I want to read a Int32 from it.
I tried using dataviews but it doesn't work as expected for me :

```
vWebSocket=new WebSocket("http://127.0.0.1:8081","",{perMessageDeflate:true});
wWebSocket.on('message', function(prData,prFlags)
 {
  var vDataView=new DataView(prData.buffer);
  var vLong=vDataView.getInt32(0,true);
  console.log('Datas received'+vLong);
 }
```

Originally I sended (from a delphi application using sgcWebSocket) the "350000" int32,

- in the debugger prData is seen as a Uint8Array
- it contains the correct bytes values [48,87,5,0]
- but in fine vlong contains 1717920771 or 154220088 (I tried changing the endianess) instead of 350000

I'm quite new to Javascript so I assume I must be making a beginner's mistake, I googled arround but I didn't found any clues

Comment: Is it possible that prData *isn't* a `Uint8Array`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The debugger seems to think it is an `UInt8Array`. And it contains `0x30`, `0x57`, `0x05`, `0x00`, which is indeed the big-endian (network) form of `350000`, or `0x00055730`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I saw that Henry said that, I was asking for confirmation, because if it really were a Uint8Array with those contents, the `DataView` code shown would work. (https://jsfiddle.net/xbh6qr6v/) So that suggests...it isn't.

Comment: I tested with every other kind of typed array (initializing four entries with the values shown), and none gives the values you're getting; but `new DataView(prData.buffer)` would be throwing an exception if `prData.buffer` weren't an `ArrayBuffer`. So with respect, that suggests some kind of observation error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your observations, I digged and I finally found the issue.
although the debugger was seeing prData as a Uint8Array it was in fact a buffer.
I realized it by looking and the "__proto__" field in the debugger (with intellij).

- In the example of TJ Crowder the "__proto__" was uInt8Array
- in my case the "__proto__" was buffer

So I changed my code to :

```
var vLong=prData.readInt32LE();
console.log('Datas received:'+vLong);
```

(Of course no more need to use a dataview)

Again thanks for your sugggestions.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question title. I actually need to read int32 from a uInt8Array.